# I want to able to test for object names in an instance variable of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance variable in a form @partnership.

Depending on how that form is called it has a associated object Landlord or Seller.  In the example below it was called by a Seller.

I want to test to see what objects exist in the @partnership instance

ie

```
 if @partnership.objectname== Seller 
   do something
 elsif parnership.objectname= Landlord
   do somethhing else
 end
```

Below is debug of the object called by a seller.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
--- !ruby/object:Partnership 
attributes: 
  name: 
  created_at: 
  updated_at: 
  default_partnership: false
attributes_cache: {}

new_record: true
sellers: []
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's probably an error when you wrote the code, but you forgot the @ in:

```
elsif parnership.objectname= Landlord
```

Second, instead of

```
@partnership.objectname== Seller
```

you should use:

```
@partnership.class == Seller
```

or

```
@partnership.is_a? Seller
```

But I dont see why you want to do that: it's not want you want. A partnership is not a Seller or a Landlord, right?
How is defined the association between Partnership and sellers/landlords ? Are you using polymorphism ?

Comment: Thanks Wes.  This issue I am having is this.